# How to run a piece of code only once everyday?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I'm using Flutter. How do I run a function once every day? I cannot use a loop or a async functions to run once every 24 hours. Is there a way this can be achieved?

I want to run it in splash screen when the user opens the app.

Comment: do you want to run this function in background or when app is open.?

Comment: I want to run it in splash screen. @DeepakRor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work for you. Call this function from splash

```
checkIsTodayVisit() async {
  Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  SharedPreferences preferences = await _prefs;
  String lastVisitDate = preferences.get("mDateKey");

  String toDayDate = DateTime.now().day.toString(); // Here is you just get only date not Time.

  if (toDayDate == lastVisitDate) {
    // this is the user same day visit again and again

  } else {
    // this is the user first time visit
    preferences.setString("mDateKey", toDayDate);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

i tried ,see if it works

```
void main() async {
      //checking current date
      final currentdate = new DateTime.now().day;
      //you need to import this Shared preferences plugin 
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      //getting last date 
      int lastDay = (prefs.getInt('day') ?? 0);
      
      //check is code already display or not
      if(currentdate!=lastDay){
         await prefs.setInt('day', currentdate);
        //your code will run once in day
        print("hello will display once")
      }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
    @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), handleScreenChange);
      }

handleScreenChange() {
  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => HomeScreen(),
  ));
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // You can chnage splash screen view like you want
  return Container(child: Text('SplashScreen'));
}
}
```

Comment: What does that have to do with the question?